# How to take update from source to Github Mirrored Repository?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-fetch, git-mirror

After following the below instructions, i was able to create a mirror in my GitHub account. But after that how to take update from the source repository.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository

> Open Git Bash.
>
> Create a bare clone of the repository.
>
> $ git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
>   Mirror-push to the new repository.
>
> $ cd old-repository.git $ git push --mirror
>   https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git Remove the temporary
>   local repository you created in step 1.
>
> $ cd .. $ rm -rf old-repository.git

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the same bare clone and mirror push would update the repository from source.

You can employ the same steps each time you'd like to update your mirror:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository